# Can not run hadoop localy using cygwin

Tags: linux, hadoop, cygwin

I am new to hadoop so i am following this [tuturial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html) to install a single node on my computer. My OS is Windows 7 so I installed cygwin. In the tuturial I've been asked to:

**Try the following command:**

**$ bin/hadoop**

but when I try it I get this response:

**-bash: binhadoop: command not found**

The file "hadoop" is in the directory and have not changed it. As I mentioned I am new to Hadoop and Linux\Cygwin so maybe its something trivial that I do wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command would be $cd /bin/hadoop  to change directory. Use Linux for making things easier I would suggest.